# Pdf Generation Using ITextSharp for Cheque Like Structure

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I have requirement of online cheque generation.
I am using ,

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

I have dynamic cheque Height and width,font and fontsize.
And obviously cheque number with account information in all page of document.

My code goes like this

```
Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(width, height), 0, 0, 0, 0);
string path = Server.MapPath("~/REPORTFILES");
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path + "/cheque.pdf",FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
BaseFont f_cn = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\calibri.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
for (int i = fromchq; i <= tochq; i++)
            {
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetFontAndSize(f_cn, 14);
            cb.SetFontAndSize(f_cn, fontsize);
            cb.SetTextMatrix(cord_x, cord_y);
            cb.ShowText(getProperty(propertyName,i.ToString().PadLeft(FromChqNo.Length, '0')));
            cb.EndText();
            doc.NewPage();
}
```

Here cord_x and cord_y is the co-ordinate location of that text.

Everything  works fine i got pdf of my custom size.
like this :[image]

But while printing it into the cheque
its work fine untill it has space enough to print single page. my xps image is attached bellow.[image]

Area in red curve is skiped to be printed.
I mean to ask how can i make it posible that it will print serially, and completely fullfill my requirement that a cheque leaf of any height ,width,font will be printed serially. Thank you all in advance and also thanks for reading my problem.

Comment: So you are making a multiple page PDF and that is working, right? When you try to print those multiple pages combined into a single, however, it will only fit 3 on a page instead of 4? Is that the problem?

Comment: Chris sory for late response . I got solution finally. All work above well good enough and i made extra printer setup. Using Custom page option.